# SessionLock problems within ThreadPool

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, session

I have a web application which appears to be suffering from Sessions being locked for (apparent) random requests. I'm aware of the limitations of sessions, that they are locked to make them thread-safe, so concurrent sessions are unavailable with the .Net session provider.

My question however relates to the creation of threads within the TreadPool. My web application does a lot of background tasks which are sometimes triggered indirectly by user requests.

I've recently noticed that creating threads within the ThreadPool retains access to the users session; which I suspect is causing the random session locking experienced on the site (ie. the user cannot make any further subsequent requests until the initial request has completed and released the session). I have proved access to the session is possible by doing the following in a sample page and making multiple requests to see the results of the session variables changed via a thread, which it does.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Session["Cow"] == null)
    Session["Cow"] = "Moo";
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => { threadedMethod(); });
  Response.Write((string)Session["Cow"]);
}

private void threadedMethod()
{
  // Detect if this has access to session
  Session["Cow"] = "Grass! " + new Random().Next(100);
}
```

When I create threads, I had previously assumed that session data was unable to be accessed; Now I realise that this is automatically loaded if available, and is causing the session locking problems as a result.

Does anyone know how to prevent the thread from being passed session and other client related details; with the aim to prevent any Session locking problems that it may cause?

Comment: This behavior is by design to make it state safe, if you are writing anything in session others have to wait till the request if processed. As far as performance goes you can use readonly session or disable session but that wont for for you as you need to write in session. You can try custom session data provider.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.timvasil.com/blog14/post/2008/04/16/Handling-multiple-simultaneous-requests-from-a-user-in-ASPNET.aspx

Comment: I think you have mis-understood. The thread that is created has access to the session; however I want to threadedMethod to perform server related tasks which take an amount of time, and has no need to access session related data. How do I turn this off, while still maintaining write access to the user's original request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session is locked by design as stated in comments. But in your example, Session is taken from Page class instance. So do method threadedMethod static and you will not be connected to session. If you need data from session in your worker thread - pass it as parameters.

Comment: Your right, if I make the method static I can no longer access the session. If it's not static then the thread can access it. I've just checked and my threaded methods in my project and they are actually defined as static, so I'm guessing this suggests something else is locking the session? :|

Comment: I've found a couple of entries within the global which do not reference a static method, thus locking the session. Thanks very much!